# How to limit a function to run 5 times? Javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I'm trying to limit a function to run 5 times only with no success.
So the idea of the exercise is to create a function Person() that ask for a person's [name, surname and age] and ask for the user information 5 times.
My problem is to limit the function, at the moment i can add as many user's as i want not only 5.

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="form-box">
            <h1 id="title">Exercise</h1>
            <form>
                <div class="input-group" id="name-field">
                    
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Nome" class='firstName' id="firstName-input">
                    
                   
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Apelido" class="lastName" id="lastName-input">
                    
                    
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Idade" class="age" id="age-input">
                    
                    <div class="btn-field">
                    <button type="button" class="btn-adicionar" id="btn-adicionar" onclick="Person()">Add</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-mostrar" id="btn-mostrar" onclick="Show()">Show</button>
                    </div>
                    <p id="p"></p>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
let Persona = [];
Persona.values = {
    inputs: [],
    labels: {
        n: ' Name: ',
        a: ' Surname: ',
        i: ' Age: ',
    },
};

    function Adicionar() {
        
    
            let firstName = document.getElementById('firstName-input').value;
            let lastName = document.getElementById('lastName-input').value;
            let age = document.getElementById('age-input').value;

            Persona.values.inputs.push({
                firstName: firstName,
                lastName: lastName,
                age: age,
            });
        
        
    }

    function Show() {
        let text = '';
            
            
                for (var i = 0; i < Persona.values.inputs.length; i++) {
        
                    text += "<div class='outrow'>";

                    text += "<span class='lab'>" + Persona.values.labels.n + '</span>';
                    text +=
                        "<span class='outv'>" +
                        Persona.values.inputs[i].firstName +
                        '</span>';
                    text += "<span class='lab'>" + Persona.values.labels.a + '</span>';
                    text +=
                        "<span class='outv'>" +
                        Persona.values.inputs[i].lastName +
                        '</span>';
                    text += "<span class='lab'>" + Persona.values.labels.i + '</span>';
                    text +=
                        "<span class='outv'>" + Persona.values.inputs[i].age + '</span>';
                    text += '</div>';
                }
            
        let result = document.getElementById('p');
        result.innerHTML = text;
    }
```

I've tried to use an if statement but still have the same result.

````
 function Person() {
        let number = 0
    if (number < 5) {
            let firstName = document.getElementById('firstName-input').value;
            let lastName = document.getElementById('lastName-input').value;
            let age = document.getElementById('age-input').value;

            Persona.values.inputs.push({
                firstName: firstName,
                lastName: lastName,
                age: age,
            });
         number++
        }
        
    }```
````

Comment: Use a global variable to track this and not local variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't need the `counter` variable at all, just check `Persona.values.inputs.length`.

```
function Person() {
    if (Persona.values.inputs.length < 5) {
        let firstName = document.getElementById('firstName-input').value;            
        let lastName = document.getElementById('lastName-input').value;
        let age = document.getElementById('age-input').value;

        Persona.values.inputs.push({
            firstName: firstName,
            lastName: lastName,
            age: age,
        });
    }
}
```

You can also assign input values directly to the object and avoid creating unnecessary variables

```
function Person() {
    if (Persona.values.inputs.length < 5) {
        Persona.values.inputs.push({
            firstName: document.getElementById('firstName-input').value,
            lastName: document.getElementById('lastName-input').value,
            age: document.getElementById('age-input').value,
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding your `number` counter variable inside the function that you want to limit, so everytime you call this function `number` will be reset to zero having no effect on the following condition. You actually want to declare your number variable as a global variable so it doesn't reset:

```js
let number = 0 

function Person() {
  if(number < 5) {...}
  number++
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If for whatever reason you need to keep track of this on the function itself you can use a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures):

```js
let Person = (function () {
  let number = 1;
  return function () {
     if(number <= 5) {
        console.log(`Called ${number} times`);
     }
     number++
  }
})();
for (let i = 0; i < 100;i++) Person();
```

This defines a function along with a variable which is external to that function.